# Web.config Rewrite particular subfolders to querystrings

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, query-string

I have searched and tried many Rewrite rules but no one matched my requierement. In a particular folder (**not entire the website**) say `http://www.example.com/company/` I want to rewrite all subfolders to execute a page with querystring. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/company/test
```

should show the content of

```
http://www.example.com/company/index.aspx?title=test
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575775/4700922) was the closest answer to my question but is about the root folder of website not a particular folder so I could not figur out the logic of {R:0} {R:1} etc.

```
 <rule name="Redirector" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/*" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.aspx?q={PATH_INFO}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me:

```
<rule name="RedirectFolder" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(^company/(.*))|(^company$)" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/*" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="./company/index.aspx?q={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```